# When commit happens in case of getHibernateTemplate()

Tags: spring, hibernate

I am using Spring Hibernate integration in my application and DAO classes are extending `HibernateDaoSupport`.
Suppose I save some object using the code `getHibernateTemplate().save(object)`
Using hibernate template I don't need to explicitly commit the transaction. I want to know at what point data is committed.

Consider the below code snippet

```
public void saveObject(){
   .......
   getHibernateTemplate().save(object1);
   ....
   ....
   getHibernateTemplate().save(object2);
 }
```

In the above code, exactly at what point `object1` will be inserted into the DB..after `getHibernateTemplate().save(object1);` or at the end of method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the transaction manager configuration and/or flush mode settings.
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/FlushMode.html

Comment: Assume that I haven't configured any Transaction Management in the project i.e. relyinh on default transaction provided by hibernate template neither using any FlushMode..in that case at what point commit happens?

Comment: default is auto flush. you can check you flushmode by calling for example:   Session s = sessionFactory.openSession();
  System.out.println("my flush mode" + s.getFlushMode());

Answer (score 0):

You should use this:

```java
  @Override
    public void addAccount(Account account) {

        hibernateTemplate.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().beginTransaction();
        hibernateTemplate.saveOrUpdate(account);
        hibernateTemplate.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().getTransaction().commit();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Neither one.

In default configuration, `insert` statements are executed at last moment they can, I mean hibernate keeps them till end of transaction, or any other point it shall (if there are `flush` commands, some other select commands....).

But committing does not depend on this at all, committing happens just when you (or Spring!) commits the transaction. So it depends on how do you manage transaction, if you are using Spring's declarative transaction management, then it is important which method has transaction attribute, and what attribute it gots.